StacksEditor upload
I'm trying to change the upload URL for my images in stackeditor.  Using this code, I never see anything logging within the handler at all and cannot find a working example anywhere.  I've also tried to implement a custom stimulus controller, and while I managed to register it I still can't figure out how to customize upload.
const myStacksEditor = new window.stacksEditor.StacksEditor(
    editorContainer,
    "*Your* **markdown** here",
    {
        parserFeatures: {
            tables: true,
            fencedCodeBlocks: true
        },
        upload: {
            handler: {
                upload: async (files) => {
                    console.log('Custom upload handler called');
                    console.log('Files:', files);

                    try {
                        const uploadedFiles = files.map(file => {
                            console.log('Uploading file:', file.name);
                            return URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        });

                        console.log('Uploaded files:', uploadedFiles);
                        return uploadedFiles;
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Upload failed:', error);
                        throw error;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

